# What is the difference between sprintf and printf in C?

Tags: c, cs50

I am working on pset4 of CS50 and really confused on where to use sprintf in recover.c problem of CS50.I want to know what and where to exactly use sprintf and printf.

Comment: read the man pages.

Comment: Well: the type of their first argument is different.

Comment: Google is your friend, you know.

Comment: "... where to exactly use ..": **only** in places where the function does what you need to do at that place. It makes no sense to use one if it doesn't do what you want it to do anyway, so in that case, use the other. (This advice can be extended to apply to all functions, with a final catch-all: if there is no such function, then write it.)

Comment: @RadLexus: If there is no such function, then confirm that such a function's existence makes sense; if it does, then determine why nobody has written it yet; if there is no good reason (which is highly unlikely!) then write it.

Comment: @LRiO: one can even extend this philosophy to the entire width and depth of Software Development. "Is there software that does *x*? Is it useful to have software doing *x*?" If no & yes, ... Profit!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sprintf` formats a string and writes it into the character array specified by the first argument (assuming sufficient space); `printf` formats a string and writes it to `stdout`.

Ex: you can do this with `sprintf`:

```
char buffer[100];
sprintf(buffer, "My name is %s and I am %d years old", "John Doe", 25);
// buffer now contains "My name is John Doe and I am 25 years old"
```

However, if you want to write a formatted string to the standard output stream, you need to use `printf` (or `fprintf` with `stdout` as the first argument):

```
printf("My name is %s and I am %d years old", "John Doe", 25);
// the text "My name is John Doe and I am 25 years old" gets printed to the stdout stream
```

Comment: Wow thanks man it really helped me.

Comment: Actually it didn't. It saved you from learning how to perform basic research. Tsk.